# C# Windows Forms MS-Chart control min and max

Tags: c#, sql, mschart

I have a DateTimePicker when selecting time, it calls a SQL stored procedure, a daily average of the points made ​​in that day,
The problem is that when I give the minimum and maximum values do not appear to me, and if I do not put the maximum and minimum values occur but the date is wrong, the  minimum  is s `00:00.00 29/12/1989` and the maximum is `23/01/1900 00: 00.00`
I do not appear for the selected date values​​, I appears that data from the past.
That is the portion of code:

```
#region Day
private void check_Day_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        try
        {
            if (check_Day.Checked == true)
            {
                chartHistory.DataSource = null;
                chartHistory.DataBind();
                checkShift.Enabled = false;
                check_Month.Enabled = false;
                check_TimePeriod.Enabled = false;
                dateTimePicker_day.Enabled = true;
                EventHandler Delegate_dateTimePicker_day = null;
                Delegate_dateTimePicker_day = delegate(System.Object o, System.EventArgs ee)
                {
                    string data = dateTimePicker_day.Value.ToShortDateString();
                    chartHistory.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
                    chartHistory.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Hours;
                    /*
                   var date = DateTime.Parse(data.ToString());
                   DateTime comp = Convert.ToDateTime(date.ToCustomFormat());
                   Console.Write(comp.ToString());
                   */
                   DateTime date_one = Convert.ToDateTime(data.ToString());
                   TimeSpan ts_one = new TimeSpan(00,00,00);
                   DateTime compDate_one = date_one.Date + ts_one;
                   DateTime date_two = Convert.ToDateTime(data.ToString());                        
                   TimeSpan ts_two = new TimeSpan(23, 59, 59);
                   DateTime compDate_two = date_two.Date + ts_two;
                   objConnect = new DatabaseConnection();
                   objConnect.SQL_Param_Date = data;
                   objConnect.ProcedureSql = "[dbo].[sp_DayAverage_Chart]";
                   ds = objConnect.GetConnection;
                   chartHistory.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                   chartHistory.DataBind();
                   //double min = compDate_one.ToOADate();
                   //double max = compDate_two.ToOADate();
                   chartHistory.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = compDate_one.ToOADate();
                   chartHistory.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = compDate_two.ToOADate();
                   chartHistory.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1;
                   Console.Write("Second Data:" + data + "\n");
                   Console.Write("Datetime date_one:" + date_one.ToString() + "\n");
                   Console.Write("Compose Date:" + compDate_one + "\n");
                   Console.Write("Datetime date_two:" + date_two.ToString() + "\n");
                   Console.Write("Compose Date Two:" + compDate_two + "\n");
                   Console.Write("Min:" + compDate_one + "\n");
                   Console.Write("Max:" + compDate_two + "\n");
                };
                dateTimePicker_day.ValueChanged += Delegate_dateTimePicker_day;
            }
            else
            {
                checkShift.Enabled = true;
                check_Month.Enabled = true;
                check_TimePeriod.Enabled = true;
                dateTimePicker_day.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        { 
            MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
        } 
    }
```

Update Post:

Example:
When you select a date in DateTimePicker (eg 06/05/2014) Format
double min = 41795.0 (06/05/2014 00:00.00), and double max = 41795.999988425923 (06/05/2014 23:59:59) but in this interval time displays nothing

If I don't set the minimum and maximum at  the chart my X axis it's start from 29/12/1898 00:00.00 and it's end at 23/01/1900 00:00.00

Comment: Could you reword you post to be more clear, it is difficult to understand. Try telling us in more simple and separated thoughts the following: Your situation, your problem, and what behavior you would like changed.